# Java comparing count with user input errors

Tags: java

I am creating a while loop to determine `if (count == numbers.length)` then the loop will break out of the while. Whenever I run print statements to see where I am going wrong, whatever my count is set to, my numbers.length is also set to the same thing no matter how many numbers I actually input if any. How can I fix this error?

```
// Create a scanner to read user input
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

// Prompts user to enter the integer count
System.out.print("How many integers would you like to enter: ");
int count = s.nextInt();
s.nextLine();
// s.nextLine() closes the previous scanner reader

while(true) {

   // Prompts user to enter the integer numbers here based on count
   System.out.print("\nEnter your integer numbers here: ");
   int [] numbers = new int[count];
   Scanner numScanner = new Scanner(s.nextLine());

   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      if (numScanner.hasNextInt()) {
          numbers[i] = numScanner.nextInt();
          if (numbers.length == count) {
            break;
          }
      }
      else {
          System.out.print("Must enter the correct amount of numbers");
      }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int [] numbers = new int[count];
```

This line creates a `count`-sized array of ints. So at the point you initialize your array its size will be equal to `count`. Eventually, all the values in the array will be 0.

You may want to use a List instead. e.g.:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
...
numbers.add(numScanner.nextInt());
```

To break the loop when necessary:

```
if (numbers.size() == count){
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here:

First, you'll want to use `i`, not `numbers.length`, as the former will increment for each number entered, whereas the later will always be the same as `count`.

Second, a `break` will not exit the `while` loop, but rather just the `for` loop.  Since you want to exit the `while` loop as well, you can use a boolean value instead of `while (true)`, then set that value to `false`.

```
boolean needInput = true;
while (needInput) {
    ....
    if (i == count) {
        needInput = false;
        break;
    }
}
```